# Framework w3 menu accordion transition animated, does not work

Tags: javascript, css

How can I close an accordion button when opening a second or third button?

I am using the css3 code below and its java script.

Currently clicking on a button it is open when clicking another ...

Thanks for the help.

```
    "<div class="w3-accordion w3-teal">

      <button onclick="myFunction('Button1')" class="w3-btn-block w3-center  w3comp-button-blue2 w3-text-white"><h3>Cadastro Demandas</h3></button>
      <div id="Button1" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container">
        <div w3-include-html="file01.asp"></div>
      </div>
         <p></p>

      <button onclick="myFunction('Button2')" class="w3-btn-block w3-center  w3comp-button-blue2  w3-text-white"><h3>Consulta Demandas</h3></button>
      <div id="Button2" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container">
        <div w3-include-html="file2.asp"></div>
      </div>
          <p></p>

       <button onclick="myFunction('Button3')" class="w3-btn-block w3-center  w3comp-button-green  w3-text-white"><h3>Consulta Legislação</h3></button>
       <div id="Button3" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container">
         <div w3-include-html="file3.asp"></div>
       </div>
         <p></p>
       </div>"

  <script>
  function myFunction(id) {
      var x = document.getElementById(id);
      if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
          x.className += " w3-show";
      } else {
          x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
      }
  }
  </script>
```

The following is the CSS code I'm using ... highlighting the tags I'm applying because the framework is very large ...

```
*{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
html{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,menu,nav,section,summary{display:block}
audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}
audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}
a{background-color:transparent}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}
dfn{font-style:italic}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}
small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}
sup{top:-0.5em}sub{bottom:-0.25em}
img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure{margin:1em 40px}
hr{-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}
code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}
button,input,select,textarea{font:inherit;margin:0}
button{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}
button,html input[type=button],input[type=reset],input[type=submit]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}
button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}
button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}
input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]{padding:0}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}
input[type=search]{box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-appearance:textfield;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box}
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}
fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}
legend{border:0;padding:0}pre,textarea{overflow:auto}
html,body{font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:1.5}html{overflow-x:hidden}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,.w3-slim,.w3-wide{font-family:"Segoe UI",Arial,sans-serif}
h1{font-size:36px}h2{font-size:30px}h3{font-size:24px}h4{font-size:20px}h5{font-size:18px}h6{font-size:16px}
.w3-serif{font-family:"Times New Roman",Times,serif}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-weight:400;margin:10px 0}.w3-wide{letter-spacing:4px}
h1 a,h2 a,h3 a,h4 a,h5 a,h6 a{font-weight:inherit}
hr{height:0;border:0;border-top:1px solid #eee;margin:20px 0}
img{margin-bottom:-5px}a{color:inherit}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;width:100%;display:table}
table,th,td{border:none}.w3-table-all{border:1px solid #ccc}
.w3-navbar a,.w3-topnav a,.w3-sidenav a,.w3-dropdown-content a,.w3-accordion-content a,.w3-dropnav a{text-decoration:none!important}
.w3-navbar a,.w3-sidenav a,.w3-pagination li a,.w3-hoverable tbody tr,.w3-hoverable li,.w3-accordion-content a,.w3-dropdown-content a,.w3-dropdown-click:hover,.w3-dropdown-hover:hover,.w3-opennav,.w3-closenav,.w3-closebtn,
.w3-accordion {width:100%;cursor:pointer}
.w3-accordion-content{cursor:auto;display:none;position:relative;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
.w3-accordion-content a{padding:6px 16px;display:block}.w3-accordion-content a:hover{background-color:#ccc}
.w3-container:after,.w3-row:after,.w3-row-padding:after,.w3-topnav:after,.w3-clear:after,.w3-btn-group:before,.w3-btn-group:after,.w3-btn-bar:before,.w3-btn-bar:after
.w3-container{padding:0.01em 16px}
.w3-btn,.w3-btn-block{border:none;display:inline-block;outline:0;padding:6px 16px;vertical-align:middle;overflow:hidden;text-decoration:none!important;color:#fff;background-color:#000;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;white-space:nowrap}
.w3-btn.w3-disabled *,.w3-btn-block.w3-disabled,.w3-btn-floating.w3-disabled *,.w3-btn:disabled *,.w3-btn-floating:disabled *{pointer-events:none}
.w3-btn.w3-disabled:hover,.w3-btn-block.w3-disabled:hover,.w3-btn:disabled:hover,.w3-btn-floating.w3-disabled:hover,.w3-btn-floating:disabled:hover,
.w3-btn:hover,.w3-btn-block:hover,.w3-btn-floating:hover,.w3-btn-floating-large:hover{box-shadow:0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19)}
.w3-btn-block{width:100%}
.w3-btn,.w3-btn-floating,.w3-dropnav a,.w3-btn-floating-large,.w3-btn-block,.w3-hover-shadow,.w3-hover-opacity,
```

Comment: Where is the css3 code?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have already attached the CSS that I am using.

Comment: could you create a fiddle for this one